# JQuery How to select all the li items in a ul which DO NOT have a particular CLASS

Tags: jquery, list

Here is the sample html I have.

```
<ul id="alist">
<li class="red">...</li>
<li class="blue">...</li>
<li class="red">...</li>
<li class="green">...</li>
</ul>
```

Aim: To select all the elements in the list which don't have 'red' class and fade them out.

This is what I have so far. I know it's close, but either there's a bug in the code or in the selector somewhere.

```
$('#alist :not(:has(.red))').fadeOut('slow');
```

I also tried

```
$('#alist li :not(:has(.red))').fadeOut('slow');

$('#alist :not(:has(li.red))').fadeOut('slow');
```

None of them are working (obviously). But when I tried to filter something inside the ul it does. So with a html as:

```
<li><a class="red">...</li>
.
.
.
<li><a class="green">...</li>
```

and made the jquery selector

```
$('#alist li :not(:has(a.red))').fadeOut('slow');
```

it works.

So why isn't JQuery not letting me filter li classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:has` looks at the children of elements. You just need to look at the element's class itself. So:

```
$('#alist :not(.red)').fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#alist li a').not('.red').parent().fadeOut('slow');
```

This selects all anchor tags that do now have `red` as a class and fades out the parent `li`

Comment: Also check the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) - slower on IE, faster on browsers with CSS3 support ([see results](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not))

Comment: @Neal: he wants to match the first version of the html (so no `a` and `.parent()`)

Comment: @Dan im not si sure about that. and also don't assume the OP is a `he`

Comment: @Neal: quoting the OP: *"Aim: To select all the elements in the list which don't have 'red' class and fade them out."*, *"why isn't JQuery not letting me filter li classes?"*. Lolz about criticizing my use of `he`, I don't think that in this informal scenario it's of any importance, especially as the username is not indicative of gender. I don't think he/she would be offended, I wouldn't

Comment: @Dan i meant to put a `:-P` at the end of my last comment, guess i forgot it. hmmm i don't know, whatever the OP wants, the OP chose already, and this is here for future users

Comment: @Neal `:)` it felt like it was missing a `:-P`. Anyway maybe `he`'ll need your answer some day :-P

Comment: thanks Neal - that works as well. I went with the first suggestion as it too worked and used filters which i find are just a little quicker (although i have no way to conclusively prove this). btw - I'm a He :)